# How to create a data frame consisting of multiple diagonals of a matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a 60 x 120 matrix which is essentially 2 60 x 60 matrices, and I want to create a data frame which consists of the two diagonals of the respective matrices. I understand I can split the matrices, however I will be using a 60 x 60000 matrix later. How can I go about doing this?

The following is my attempt so far:

```
MatrixFemale <- as.matrix(MortalityFemale)

b <- seq(1,1000) * 60

c <- c(1, b) - 1

for (x in c) {
    Data <- data.frame(diag(MatrixFemale[, -(1:x)]))
}
```

I know this does not work, but I am really not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Hi. The data is essentially a simulation of mortality rates which have been generated after fitting a model to a built in data set which comes from the human mortality database via the demography package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. Basically we can get the column indexes of each submatrix in a list, then extract the individual submatrices into the list, and finally get the diagonal of each submatrix and bind into a dataframe. (you could even combine the last two steps but I think this is a bit clearer)

```r
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
mat <- cbind(diag(60), diag(60) + 1) # Example 60 x 120 matrix with diagonals 1 and 2
split(1:ncol(mat), rep(1:(ncol(mat) / 60), each = 60)) %>% # Get column indexes for submatrices
  map(~ mat[, .]) %>% # List of the 60 x 60 submatrices
  map_dfc(diag) # Get diagonal of each submatrix and bind into data frame columns
#> # A tibble: 60 x 2
#>      `1`   `2`
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     2
#>  2     1     2
#>  3     1     2
#>  4     1     2
#>  5     1     2
#>  6     1     2
#>  7     1     2
#>  8     1     2
#>  9     1     2
#> 10     1     2
#> # ... with 50 more rows
```

Created on 2018-10-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just wondering how do I use this data frame for additional calculations because I keep getting an error involving a .f argument.

Comment: You probably need to assign the result to something, here i just print it to console

Comment: I tried doing something like `a <- map_dfc(diag)` however it doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: put it at the beginning of the pipe, like `a <- split(...` See https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/